# Checkered plane painted in 10 colors.Any two adjacent cells are colored in different colors .

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

Checkered plane painted in 10 colors.  (Each cell is colored one color, all colors are present.) Any two adjacent cells are colored in different colors. Let us say a pair of colors is good if there are two neighboring cells painted in these colors. What is the least number of good pairs?

I have to use graphs,
vertices of graph will be cells that are coloured ,and edges will mean neighbor cells
but I don't know how to find minimum number of neighbor colour variations.

Answer (score 1):

If half the cells are coloured *red* in a checkerboard pattern then the answer seems to be $10-1=9$

You will not be able to do better than that as there must be a path through all $10$ colours and so at least $9$ pairs of distinct changes

Comment: what if you can colour them other way such that you get 8 pairs of distinct changes?

Comment: @DeltaAccount You will find you cannot, for the reason I gave.  You start at a particular colour and visit nine more.  Each time you first visit a particular colour you get a new pair, and so the path must involve at least nine pairs

Answer (score 0):

assume vertexes of graph are colours
and two vertecies are adjacent if that pair of colours exists on checkered plane.
The graph must be connected, because from any color you can go to to any other on plane.
the minimum number of edges for the Connected graph is $n-1$ And we have the number of vertices $10$ so the minimum  number of edges will be $9$.
Now we need to show that $9$ is possibe.
We need to find an example
which is what @Henry did.